# Background expands along with list

Tags: html, css, list

I've got a problem with my list made with HTML/CSS.

The third button on my navigation menu list is another list, but when I'm pointing the cursor on it, the list expands along with the 'background-color' under the whole navigation menu. How to make that list to expand only the area under the button?

Here's my part of CSS code

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
ol a {
  display: block;
}
ol > li {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
}
ol li a {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px 15px 15px;
}
ol li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
ol > li > ul {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ol > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
ol > li > ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><a href="index.html"> &#9745; Strona główna</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html"> &#9745; Muzyka</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html"> &#9745; Streetwear</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Ubrania</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Buty</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html"> &#9745; Wideo</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html"> &#9745; Lifestyle</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html"> &#9745; O nas</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Have you tried Height Auto?

Comment: Add your Html part

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it already

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS code you set the overflow value of 'ol' elements to 'hidden'. Overflow: hidden elements will try to wrap their children elements, even if normally they wouldn't.

In this case, because of this property, everything inside your ordered list gets wrapped in it.

To solve this, you can remove the overflow or background color of ordered lists (ol) in your CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add 'clearfix' to ol:

   ol::after {
     content: '';
     display: table;
     clear: both;
   }
2. add `position: relative;` to your `ol > li` style;
3. add `position: absolute; top: 79px; left: 0;` to `ol > li > ul` where 79px is a height of your ol.

Here is your `ol>li>ul`: http://codepen.io/g1un/pen/ozkdZV